# Android program with unused Swing code inside

Tags: java, android, swing

I am designing a new software which is going to be Swing based Java application. I am currently completely decoupled the GUI layer and business layer hoping to porting my application to Android someday. When I am porting it to Android I am planing to just write a new inheritance to my `GUIAbstractFactory`.

Will Android API build my code base which has unused Swing dependencies or I will be forced to delete those classes who reference Swing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should compile fine so long as the `rt.jar` of a J2SE is on the compilation class-path.

Comment: Wow!  It's nice to have someone thank me for edits, a lot of people complain..  :)

Comment: Well, I did write "programram" instead of writing "program" :) and forgot to spell check. In my opinion you prevented utter shame of me,a senior software programmer who can not spell "program".